# What type of screw/bolt has expandable wings behind the wall surface?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, screws, bolts

Do you know what type of screw and bolt this is? Do you know the best way to unscrew it? It attaches my CCTV camera to the ceiling plaster (dry wall).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Those are "Mollys": (hollow wall anchors)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molly_(fastener)

They don't come out,

the screw comes out (it's long so it comes out slowly), but the anchor part will stay.

It might be possible to drill out the anchor part from the front

Or maybe cut off the arms at the back, remove the nut fold up the stubs and eject the anchor body

Comment: The hollow wall anchors don't come out because the hole into which they were placed is smaller than the spread legs of the anchor. In the photo, the back side is accessible. Once the bolt is removed, the anchor will fall away, yes?

Comment: you'll have to break up the  sheet metal part, it has a flange on the outside, and  the the arms you see on the inside ,  cut away the arms or the flange and it will fall out (or in) leaving a bare hole,

Comment: I use a needle-nose pliers to grasp and snap off the front flange (which is usually in two halves), then push the resulting sleeve into the wall for patching.

Comment: Another method:  Unscrew the fastener bolt until it's down to its last few threads, then tap on it with a hammer.  Basically you are trying to cause the folded legs back to the original flat.  Or near flat, at some point you can pull on it and use the force against the hole to help.